# Do ships sink nowadays?

Tags: safety, sea-travel

People who have a phobia of traveling by air point out that that traveling by sea is safer. We all know that at least one aircraft a year crashes, often more, and usually all people aboard die when that happens. But what about ships? Do they sink in modern times? When did the last ship sink and what was the number of causalties? Are there any statistics around sea vessels that one can refer to?

Comment: Ships do sink.  While we don't always hear a lot about them, some of the bigger ones steal all the fanfare.  Remember the [Cost Concordia disaster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Costa_Concordia_disaster) just a couple of years ago?  32 people on board died.

Comment: Look at the mentions of ferries going down, most of those in poor countries and often with 3 to 10 times as allowed on board, often resulting in 100 or more death per occurance. But some ferries have sunk in Europe as well.

Comment: Wikipedia has a [list of maritime disasters in the 21st century](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_maritime_disasters_in_the_21st_century).

Comment: You don't care if ships in general sink. You only care if a ship you're likely to take might sink. There's a world of difference between a cruise ship, a ferry, a private yacht, an oil tanker, a fishing boat, and a container vessel.

Comment: Actually, when a plane crashes, usually either all or most people on board *survive*. Aircraft are built to keep people in them alive; for a dramatic example, [this plane](http://deicinginnovations.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/A05H0002_photo_07_lg.jpg) had *zero* deaths on board.

Comment: Ehm... when was the last time you watched the news? Last couple of years were quite bad for both air and naval transports.

Comment: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulgaria_%28ship%29 - the crew forgot to close the portholes in stormy weather and the fully intact ship filled with water and sunk. 122 people died. That was on an artificial lake, not even in the ocean.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, ships sink. Someone already mentioned the [Costa Concordia sinking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Costa_Concordia_disaster); ferries sink a fair amount as well (for instance, a South Korean ferry [sank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinking_of_the_MV_Sewol) last year with the loss of almost 300 lives. On June 1 of this year, a ferry in China [sank](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Sinking_of_Dong_Fang_Zhi_Xing) with the loss of at least 440 lives.

In addition to deaths from sinking, there are also deaths from maritime collisions, and from people falling overboard. While the sample size is tiny, a single accident on the Staten Island Ferry in 2003 with 11 deaths was enough to drive the fatality rate for US ferries well above the rate for US scheduled passenger flights.

Comment: Is that deaths/mile, deaths/trip, or both?

Comment: @Deduplicator Deaths per passenger mile.

Comment: Wonder if the other measure would have a different result, as flight are mostly longer...

Comment: @cpast and many ships do sink very regularly in non developed countries. Think of Cape Verde, Indonesia, Philippines, etc.

Comment: @Deduplicator and faster.  A jet travels maybe 50 times faster but carries maybe 1/10 the number of passengers as the Staten Island Ferry.  In the 25 minutes it takes for the ferry to move 5000 people 5 miles, an airplane could move 500 people 250 miles, so that is 1000 passenger miles per minute for the ferry and 5000 passenger miles per minute for the jet.

Comment: As another example, there was a very deadly ferry crash near Cebu, Philippines a couple of years ago. [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MV_St._Thomas_Aquinas)

Answer (score 4):

According to a [2003 report by the european transportation safety council](http://etsc.eu/wp-content/uploads/2003_transport_safety_stats_eu_overview.pdf):

> Rail and air travel are the safest modes per distance travelled, followed by bus. The passengers of trains, bus/coach and planes within the EU have the lowest fatality risk per passenger kilometre. For the average passenger trip in the EU, bus travel has a 10 times lower fatality risk than car travel and air travel within the EU has for the average flight distance about the same fatality risk per passenger kilometre as train travel and both are half as risky as travel by coach. **The risks associated with ferry travel fluctuate, but the expected fatality risk is 4 to 8 times that of train** [or air] **travel**.

(emphasis mine)

Note that this report was published in 2003, before the Costa Concordia sinking, so an updated report may put the risk from ferry travel as higher.

Answer (score 2):

Planes crash, ships sink, and cars hit bridges. The difference is the newsworthiness, and a big fireball makes better headlines than the day-after coverage of flat water.

What feeds the phobia is the speed and the level of control. When a plane crashes, it happens really quickly and there is absolutely no way anyone on board is getting out. And I say that as someone who taught sport parachuting for 10 years - the only people who escape lawn-dart mode air crashes or midair collisions are the ones sitting in ejection seats at the time. Bad landings are different, and just as unpredictable as car accidents. Sometimes you walk away, sometimes they need dental records to identify the remains.

When ships crash into each other, there is more than enough time for everyone on that side to get out their phone and videotape the incident, then finish their beer and walk down to the lifeboat deck. See youtube for examples. The Titanic took well over 2 hour to submerge. the Costa Concordia never submerged - all passengers needed to do is head uphill - the ones that died were unlucky and got trapped.

Most people consider that they can swim well enough to manage. And most cruise-goers have more than enough body fat to float quite well in salt water.  As long as the water is a reasonable temperature they have a more than reasonable chance of getting off the sinking ship and into a better one.

Comment: "Lawn-dart mode" is **extremely** rare for airliners in developed countries, though. Consider that the U.S. major airlines haven't had a **single** passenger fatality in well over 13 years, despite accounting for over 20% (maybe even 25%) of the world's airline passenger traffic. Also, in the most recent mid-air collision that I can recall in the U.S., [everyone survived and only 2 of 11 people had minor injuries](http://www.cnn.com/2013/11/03/us/wisconsin-skydivers-crash/).

Comment: @reirab reality and "People who have a phobia" don't have much to do with one another.